# Batch recursion exceeds stack limits - Error while calling a batch file from another

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've a couple of batch files, 1.bat and 2.bat and i'm calling 1.bat from 2.bat, this is what it has,

1.bat(Unraring some rar files onto a dir)

```
@echo OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@set UNRAR="C:\Program Files\Winrar\unrar.exe"
For /R "E:\Test" %%G IN (*.rar) do (
    %UNRAR% x %%G E:\Test
    @set PDIR=%%G
    @set PDIR1=!PDIR:.rar=!
    XCOPY /D /E /S /Y !PDIR1! E:\Test\Files
    RMDIR /S /Q !PDIR1!
)
pause
```

2.bat

```
call 1.bat
pause
```

1.bat runs fine on its own but when we try calling it in 2.bat gives the error

```
******  B A T C H   R E C U R S I O N  exceeds STACK limits ******
Recursion Count=594, Stack Usage=90 percent
******       B A T C H   PROCESSING IS   A B O R T E D      ******
```

How do i fix this? any ideas, thanks

Comment: Since you are recursing down the `E:\test` directory -and- putting files under `E:\test\files`, I wonder if the directory tree recursion is getting exhausted.

Comment: If you are right, @lit, then replacing `for /R "E:\Test" %%G in (*.rar) do (` by `for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /S /B /A:-D "E:\Test\*.rar"') do (` could help, because then the directory is completely enumerated *before* it is modified/extended...

Comment: The error message appears when the `call` stack is full. The code does not contain repeated `call` commands, so I cannot tell what the reason is. Nevertheless, you should clean up your code by using the quoted `set` syntax like `set "VAR=Value"` generally, then quoting every single used path, like `"%UNRAR%"`, `"%%~G"`, etc., then removing the `.rar` extension by `%%~dpnG` (so there is no need for `PDIR` and `PDIR1` variables, so delayed expansion can be disabled). You may even simplify the code by immediately extracting the `.rar` files into the destination folder rather than moving items...

Comment: figured it out, was a dump mistake from my part...it was infact repeated calls, because i had edited the second bat to call itself over and over again

Comment: @aschipfl thank you for the syntax tips..the code looks a lot cleaner now..i had only posted a part of the code, i've edited the entire code now 'Mofi' the problem is there are several rar's with different names, the task is to unzip them onto the same dir with only the latest files, so i'm resorting to copying the contents from each unrar'ed dir to a common dir